# How First countable topological space implies Fréchet Urysohn space

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

Here are the definitions:

> **Fréchet-Urysohn space:** A topological space $ X $ where for every $ A \subseteq X $ and every $ x \in \text{cl}(A) $, there exists a sequence $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ A $ converging to $ x $.

How to show that first countable spaces are Fréchet-Urysohn Space?

Let $X$ be a  first countable topological space. Let $ x \in \text{cl}(A) $ that means $x$ is a limit point of $A$. By first countability there exists a countable neighborhood base for the point $x$ say $\{N_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$  . Now for $x\in N_1$ there exists $x_1\in A$ such that $x_1\in N_1$ , similarly for $x\in N_k$ there exists $x_k\in A$ such that $x_k\in N_1$  .

Claim:$\{x_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$. Let $U$ be an arbitrary open neighborhood of $x$ then there exists an $N_i$ such that $N_i\subset U$. Then how to proceed? Maybe this procedure will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First Countable Spaces and Limit points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310930/first-countable-spaces-and-limit-points)

Comment: The neighborhood base is such that $N_{n+1}\subset N_n$ for all $n$. Notice that  for all $n\geq i$, $x_n\in N_i \subset U$.

Comment: Actually no . Because there is comment: As $X$
 is first countable, there exists a nested neighborhood $\{U_n\}$
 basis for $x$
. This is the main part to show.@Sourav Ghosh

Comment: How we can get nested neighborhood base?

Comment: @Spectrum: That is trivial: If necessary redefine $N'_1=N_1$, $N'_2=N_1\cap N_2$, $N'_3=N'_2\cap N_3$, etc

Comment: I have to check will your collection will form a neighbourhood base .

Comment: @Spectrum: It will be easy peassy, First notice that ell $N'_n$'s are open and non empty(I assume the neighborhoods are $N_n$ to begin with). Also $N'_n\subset N_n$.

Comment: Yes you are correct . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [T000183](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000183/) in the pi-Base; note that it does not reverse as the [Finite complement topology on the real numbers](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000016) and [Fort Space on the Real Numbers](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000154) are counterexamples.

As noted by Oliver in the comments, to finish your proof, simply assume $N_{n+1}\subseteq N_n$ in your countable base; then for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, pick $N_n\subseteq U$, and then $\{x_m:m\geq n\}\subseteq U$, showing convergence.